# Render v-html without extra wrapping tag?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In vue 2 `v-html` require to render an extra wrapping tag. But I'm trying something like following.

```html
<select v-model="coutnry">
 // here the options to be rendered.
</select>


<script>
...
data()}{
 return{
  countryTags:`<option value="BD">Bangladesh</option>`
 }
}
</script>
```

Since, here I can't render any extra html tag, I tired `<template v-html="countryTags">` and that didn't worked. The other solution around stackoverlflow seems little confusing. what's the proper solution ?

Comment: The `v-html` works like this. If you don't want any wrapper tag just type `{{ countryTags }}`.

Comment: that renders a string, not html

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, Vue does not provide an easy way to accomplish this (More details about the reasons can be found here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7431)

As explained there you can create a functional component to just render the HTML without a wrapper element:

```
Vue.component('html-fragment', {
  functional: true,
  props: ['html'],
  render(h, ctx) {
    const nodes = new Vue({
      beforeCreate() { this.$createElement = h }, // not necessary, but cleaner imho
      template: `<div>${ctx.props.html}</div>`
    }).$mount()._vnode.children
    return nodes
  }
})
```

This component is created by a Vue core member (LinusBorg): https://jsfiddle.net/Linusborg/mfqjk5hm/

Comment: it's 2023 now, are there ways to fix this issue?

Comment: I haven't tested this, but another option is to create a custom directive, which is described here (Vue 3): https://stackoverflow.com/a/69354385