# Vue 3 replacing the HTML tags where v-html is called with the provided HTML

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

This is about a Vue 3 app with Vite, not webpack.

For now, as you can see from [this issue on vite's issue page](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1197), vite doesn't have a convenient way of inlining SVGs without using external plugins. Vite does however, [support importing files as raw text strings](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#static-assets). As such, I had an idea to use this feature and to inline SVG's by passing the raw SVG strings into an element's `v-html`.

It actually works great, the SVG shows up on the page as expected and I can do the usual CSS transforms (the whole purpose of inlining them like this), but it's not perfect. As it currently stands, the element that receives the `v-html` directive simply places the provided HTML nested as a child. For example, if I do `<span v-html="svgRaw" />`, the final HTML comes out something like this

```html
<span>
  <svg>
    <!-- SVG attributes go here -->
  </svg>
</span>
```

Is there any way for me to essentially replace the parent element on which `v-html` is declared with the top-level element being passed to it? In the above example, it would mean the `<span>` just becomes an `<svg>`

EDIT:

Thanks to tony19 for mentioning custom directives.

My final result looks like this:

```js
// main.ts
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";

const app = createApp(App);

app.directive("inline", (element) => {
  element.replaceWith(...element.children);
});

app.mount("#app");
```

Then, in the component I simply use the directive, `<svg v-html="svgRaw" v-inline />` and it works great!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create a [custom directive](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/custom-directive.html#custom-directives) that replaces the wrapper element with its contents:

1. Use [`app.directive()`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-api.html#directive) to create a global directive, named `v-inline-svg`:

   ```js
   // main.js
   import { createApp } from 'vue'
   import App from './App.vue'

   createApp(App)
     .directive('inline-svg', el => {
       if (!el) {
         return
       }

       // copy attributes to first child
       const content = el.tagName === 'TEMPLATE' ? el.content : el
       if (content.children.length === 1) {
         ;[...el.attributes].forEach((attr) => content.firstChild.setAttribute(attr.name, attr.value))
       }

       // replace element with content
       if (el.tagName === 'TEMPLATE') {
         el.replaceWith(el.content)
       } else {
         el.replaceWith(...el.children)
       }
     })
     .mount('#app')
   ```
2. In your component, include `v-inline-svg` on the `v-html` wrapper element (also works on `<template>` in Vue 3):

   ```html
   <svg v-html="svgRaw" v-inline-svg />
   <!-- OR -->
   <template v-html="svgRaw" v-inline-svg />
   ```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vhtml-on-template-9typdx?file=src%2Fmain.js)

Comment: I had a problem with this if I used the 'v-inline' on an element and the next sibling element had vue directives on it...essentially, none of the sibling vue enabled items processed correctly.  It was as if removing/replacing the element messed up the vue 'tree' or something?  Have you seen this before?  Is there a 'proper' way to remove elements from the DOM without messing up Vue processing?  (fyi, I'm using petite-vue but guessing same thing happens in Vue proper)

Answer (score 2):

I found that using the method above works but is only good for a single rendering of the svg... The element starts throwing errors if I try to change the svg contents dynamically, not sure why but assuming that the dom replacement has something to do with it.

I modified the code slightly for my use case.

```js
    app.directive('inline-svg', {
      updated: (element) => {
        if (element.children.length === 0) {
          return
        }
        const svg = element.children[0]
        if(svg.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'svg') {
          return
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < svg.attributes.length; i++) {
          const attr = svg.attributes.item(i)
          element.setAttribute(attr.nodeName, attr.nodeValue)
        }
        svg.replaceWith(...svg.children)
      }
    })
```

In my component I have.

```html
    <svg v-if="linkType !== null" v-html="linkType" v-inline-svg></svg>
```

The directive now copies the svg attributes across from the child to the parent and then replaces the child with it's children.

Comment: Thanks for this. However, it seems this does not replace the wrapper element (at least not in my experiments with the code shown). Can you share a link to a demo of your working code?

Answer (score -1):

Coming from Vue2. I think this still works:
Instead of `span` you can use the special Vue tag `template`:

```
<template v-html="svgRaw" />
```

This will not render `<template />` as a tag itself, but render the elements given in `v-html` without a parent element.

Comment: That [renders nothing in Vue 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-bassi-yqyx7); and [renders the inert `<template>` in Vue 3](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-yonath-ld71u?file=/src/App.vue).

Comment: I'm using that in a Vue2 project and it works there...? The Vue2 sample you linked does not have anything. I'm still keeping this answer up so people can see it's wrong.

Comment: I tried this originally, but nothing registers in this case. Evan mentioned in a Github issue (I can't find it currently) that templates don't support any directives

Comment: @PeterKrebs Yes, the Vue 2 link does not "have anything" (i.e., renders nothing for the `<template v-html="html">`) because using `v-html` on `<template>` is normally not supported in Vue 2. It's interesting that it has any effect in your project. Can you share a link?

Comment: It is not a publicly available project, sorry. The Vue2 docs have an example of [using template with v-if](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Conditional-Groups-with-v-if-on-lt-template-gt), though.